# Haskell: Let statement using previous declared variable in function declaration

Tags: haskell

Say I have the function

```
foo n = foo' 1 where
    foo' n = foo' 1
    foo' x = x : foo' (x + 1)
```

As an example, say n = 5
is it possible to make the meaning of foo' n be foo' 5? So it will loop over.

Comment: Side note: you want the `cycle` function from `Data.List`: `foo n = cycle [1..n]`.  However, Nikita gave the correct answer to your specific question: you would have to use an equality test and you cannot pattern match on the value of a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you're asking for is this:

```
foo n = foo' 1 
  where
    foo' x | x == n = foo' 1
    foo' x = x : foo' (x + 1)
```

The `| x == n` part is a pattern match guard condition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there would be a simpler way of doing this using functions from Data.List

> :m + Data.List
>   let mkList to count = (concat . replicate count) [1..to]
>   mkList 5 9
>   [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
>   mkList 1 10
>   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Instead of [replicate](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3areplicate) you could also use [take](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3atake) and [cycle](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3acycle)

> let mkList to count = take count $ cycle [1..to]

take and cycle would be cheaper since you wouldn't have to go back and concat the lists.

Or you could also use [iterate](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aiterate)

```
((take 10 $ iterate (+1) 0) == [0..9]) == True
```